# What is the actual format of a Solana wallet address?

Tags: wallet, phantom, solana-wallet-adapter, address, solflare

This is a newbie question. Such as address like - `zGmof8SeyvHKnSEWv4i2mVv7MYe85D3zZqsTBjsKXSV`

Is it base64?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Addresses are base58 encoded**

From the doc:

```
const { Keypair } = require("@solana/web3.js")

let kp = Keypair.generate();

console.log(kp.publicKey.toBase58());
console.log(kp.secretKey);

// 2DVaHtcdTf7cm18Zm9VV8rKK4oSnjmTkKE6MiXe18Qsb
// Uint8Array(64) [152, 43, 116, ... 118]
```

A solana address is the public key part of a keypair that is generated with ed25519 algorithm. These are just bytes, but often you will also see it as **encoded in base58**.

- [Solana Doc On Keypair](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/javascript-reference#keypair)
- [Explanation from the Solana Bootcamp Lectures](https://youtu.be/O0uhZEfVPt8?t=558)

Comment: Also worth noting base58 is designed to eliminate confusion over 1 vs I, 0 vs O, etc by removing those characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think public keys are base58

Answer (score 0):

Any 256-bit value is a valid Solana address. By convention, these are stringified with `base58`.

While any 256-bit value is *valid*, they cannot be arbitrarily reserved for use.  There are three ways to reserve an address,

1. Generate an Ed25519 keypair and sign a transaction that specifies the corresponding `SystemInstruction::CreateAccount` instruction which reserves the public key bit value.  These addresses occupy the 256-bit values corresponding the Ed25519 curve points.
2. Find a PDA under a specific program which will CPI to the system program to reserve the address on your behalf. These addresses occupy all 256-bit values *not* on the Ed25519 curve.
3. Use the system program `*WithSeed` instructions to reserve addresses derived from a valid Ed25519 public key and a user-specified 32-byte utf-8 string. These can occupy both on- and off-curve bit value addresses. `1` and `2` should be preferred to this method